# How to hide the configure slider in MD Slider?

Tags: blocks

I've installed the MD Slider, but I would like to remove the **Edit Slider** and **Configure Slider** links in the **administrator** role. What function should I use to remove that?

Answer (score 0):

You probably would need to uncheck the permissions of the MD Slider to administrator. You can do this by going to the `admin/people/permissions`.

Comment: MD slider provides its own permissions to manager the slider and it is working properly, but it doesn't remove the "Configure Slider" and "Edit Slider" links. I just have to use the hook_menu_contextual_links_alter() to remove those links in the admin section.